# Legend objects closer between them in R

Tags: r, plot

I have to plot the following graph in R:

```
library(TTR)
x.date<-seq(1,num.years,by=20)
x.axis<-list(x1="1900",x2="1920",x3="1940",x4="1960",x5="1980",x6="2000")
plot(Annual.Mean.1, type="l",col="gray48",xaxt="n", xlab="Years",
 ylab="Temperature")
grid()
axis(1,x.date,x.axis)
SMA.1<-SMA(Annual.Mean.1,n=10
par(new=TRUE)
lines(SMA.1,col="red",type="l",lwd="2",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
SMA.2<-SMA(Annual.Mean.1,n=15)
par(new=TRUE)
lines(SMA.2,col="mediumpurple",type="l",lwd="2",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
SMA.3<-SMA(Annual.Mean.1,n=20)
lines(SMA.3,col="blue",type="l",lwd="2",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
legend("topleft",legend=c("Average Temperature","SMA 10 years","SMA 15 years","SMA 20 Years"),
   text.col=c("black","red","mediumpurple","blue"),col=c("gray48","red","mediumpurple","blue"),
   cex=0.7,lty=c(1,1,1,1))
```

The output is this: 
[image]

In the above plot, the rectangle which contain the legend is very big; i would like to obtain a smaller rectangle, like in the below plot:

[image]

How to do this?

UPDATE

As suggested in the comments, I have modified my code, in order to make it reproducible by anyone:

```
library(TTR)
set.seed(1)
x.date<-seq(1,111,by=20)
x.axis<-list(x1="1900",x2="1920",x3="1940",x4="1960",x5="1980",x6="2000")
data<-runif(111,-3,3)
plot(data, type="l",col="gray48",xaxt="n",xlab="Years",
ylab="Temperature")
grid()
axis(1,x.date,x.axis)
SMA.1<-SMA(data,n=10)
par(new=TRUE)
lines(SMA.1,col="red",type="l",lwd="2",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
SMA.2<-SMA(data,n=15)
par(new=TRUE)
lines(SMA.2,col="mediumpurple",type="l",lwd="2",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
SMA.3<-SMA(data,n=20)
lines(SMA.3,col="blue",type="l",lwd="2",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ann=FALSE)
legend("topleft",legend=c("Average Temperature","SMA 10 years","SMA 15 years","SMA 20 Years"),
   text.col=c("black","red","mediumpurple","blue"),col=c("gray48","red","mediumpurple","blue"),
   cex=0.7,lty=c(1,1,1,1))
```

I still having the same problem as explained above.

Comment: your code is not reproducible. you should also include how you are setting up the graphics device and writing to it

Comment: I know that my code is not reproducible. The data used in the plot come from a very big array that cannot be included in the code. That's why I have included the output. About the graphics device, I am using ubuntu mate 15.10, with default graphics settings.

Comment: I want to echo [rawr’s coomment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816466/legend-objects-closer-between-them-in-r#comment57375803_34816466) and link you to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to make a great reproducible example in R. A minimal reproducible example makes it easier for us to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. This also makes it possible for others to befit form your question, and the accompanying answer, in the future.  Finally, more often than not people answer their own questions when they go through that exercise.

Comment: I use `pdf('~/desktop/test.pdf', height = 6, width = 8); <rest of code>; dev.off()`  and the legend size looks reasonable to me. fyi you don't need to use `par(new=TRUE)` for `lines`. see the result [here](http://i.imgur.com/XzGRDH6.png)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much rawr!

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the value of your `cex` parameter in the `legend` call.  You have it at `cex=0.7`.  Try 0.6 or 0.5 (or lower) until you find the best size.

If that doesn't work, another approach is to just remove the box around the legend altogether with parameter `bty = "n"`.  If the background of the legend is blocking the lines in the graph, move the `legend` command up in your code so that it is drawn first and the lines are drawn over top of it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; using `cex=0.5` results in a bit smaller rectangle, but always too much big.

Comment: What about lower values?  You can keep going down, 0.4, 0.3, etc.  Does that work?

Comment: Using, as example, 0.3, I get a smaller (and reasonable) rectangle, but the size of the characters is very small and difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

The argument you probably want to use is `y.instersp`. This is the companion argument to `x.intersp`, the "character interspacing factor for horizontal (x) spacing."

Try setting it to 0.5 or 0.3.  When I set it smaller than 0.3 it scrunches the text a bit.

[y.intersp = 0.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6iln.png)

[y.intersp = 0.32; cex = 0.65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9GWf.png)

One might think that you can "un-scrunch" the text by making `cex` smaller, but it doesn't quite work that way because `cex` just scales everything, not just text size.  So shrinking `cex` will give you smaller text, but still scrunched.

You can also further reduce the interference with your figure by setting `bty = "n"` which eliminates the rectangle border of the legend and makes the legend area transparent to the lines behind it (as I have done in the 2nd example image).

```
legend("topleft",
       legend=c("Average Temperature",
                "SMA 10 years",
                "SMA 15 years",
                "SMA 20 Years"),
       text.col=c("black","red","mediumpurple","blue"),
       col=c("gray48","red","mediumpurple","blue"),
       cex=0.65,
       y.intersp = 0.32,
       bty = "n",
       lty=c(1,1,1,1))
```

[Source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/legend)